# How to change Windows 7 window border size thinner than 1?

Tags: windows-7, layout

Every window has oversized borders, i tried to go to the border settings already, but im at the minimum border size now: 1, but they are still 10px wide!

How do i get it even thinner?

Comment: You can actually set the border padding down to 0.  I'm not sure how much smaller 0 is compared to 1 but that's the first thing I change whenever I get a new system.

Comment: @gadzooks64: Yeah, I change mine to 1, as it looks stupid with the thick border padding, even on high-res screens.

Comment: @gadzooks64: please tell me how. i cant put anything lower than 1 into that box where it changes the size. is there some regkey for this?

Comment: You have to go into the Personalization menu. Window Color. Advanced appearence settings.  This will pop up a new window.  Select Border padding from the drop down box and change it to 0.

Comment: Ahh, I had the same confusion, as the trivial thing you get to select in that dialog is border *size*. From there to realize that border *padding* is a separate setting there, is subtly difficult, partly because you can't select that one by clicking around in the visualization, so it's kinda "hidden". (And also because "border size" is a generic name already matching the item you are looking for, especially as adjusting it apparently affects exactly what we wanted to change.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't test it, but [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/6283-borders-changing-width-suite-your-needs.html) may help you.

Hope that helps.
—Alberto

Comment: Ah, as paradroid said, its the Border Padding setting in the menu, thx all!

Comment: Suggest to include a brief description of the answer -- will be helpful for the crawlers and keep the answer relevent should the link die.

Comment: there is still a border

Answer (score 21):

The Border Padding setting is under the Personalization/Window Color/Advanced appearance settings.

This window will pop up.  Open the drop down and select Border Padding.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you are selecting `Border Padding` and not `Active/Inactive Window Border`, because it should go down do zero, although it is still visible at that setting?

Comment: oh lol... my bad

Comment: It tricked me, too.